# how to set a datagridview column to date format

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView and I add columns to it like this:

```
Dim col_1 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
col_1.Name = "Date"
col_1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"
data_grid.Columns.Add(col_1)
```

then I add data to the column like this:

```
data_grid.Item(1,1).Value = temp_date
```

The grid is filled with the correct data and everything works, however...when I click on the column headers, the column that shows the dates does not sort correctly (it sorts alphabetically) and I know this is because I set it up as "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn", but there is no option for a date type column. So how to I set it up as a date column so it sorts based on the date when the header is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data-type of `temp_date`? Is it a string?

Comment: Yes, temp_date's data type is String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also set the `ValueType` of the column:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).ValueType = GetType(Date)
```

Then convert `date_temp` to a Date-value before assigning this to the cell's Value.

Using `CDate` could be your first attempt:

```
data_grid.Item(1,1).Value = CDate(temp_date)
```

otherwise, investigate `Parse`, `TryParse` or `Convert`, to obtain the date-value.

Comment: OK, I did that and now it seems to be sorting based on date, but it is sorting by Day first and then Year, and the Month seems to be ignored. I set the format as MM/dd/yyyy. So now when I click on the header (DESC), it will sort all of July from the 30th to the 1st, and then August from the 31st to the first. If it is Desc, then the months should descend also.

Comment: How do I post a screenshot to show you what I mean?

Comment: I would investigate [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the date to match the formatting you have applied.

Comment: It is working Now. Assigning the data type of DateTime to the temp_date variable is what did it, but setting the ValueType would probably also work. I didn't notice the years were off. It is sorting correctly now. Thanks.